# How to read Enter key in Scanner loop

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I have a code which parse an input line.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String s = in.next();
    if (s.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
}
in.close();
```

But I need to stop a loop when user press Enter. How to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean with `stop a loop when user press Enter`? What is the input example?

Comment: "1 4 d asd 4d 56 2 34 fgfg6 67 234" = "1 4 56 2 34 67 234"

Comment: @Alex: so you want the input just one line , aren't you??

Comment: Yes, exactly! Only one line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `While` Loop

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.nextLine();
if (s.matches("[0-9]+")) {
  list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
in.close();
```

Comment: Your code don't help. It read only first number. But if I have input such "1 2 3 4 5 6" my program add only first number ("1") to list.

Comment: You just need onle one line , so you don't need to loop , then use `String s = in.nextLine();`to take your string when you press enter , after that i don't know what you will do on this string

Answer (score 0):

Your problems is on the loop part, your input just one, but you must loop based on the string length. And when you tried to parse into integer it will occur the `NumberFormatException`. See the example below:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.nextLine();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Loop based on length of user input
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

    // Checking condition for every characters on user input
    if (s.substring(i, i + 1).matches("[0-9]+")) {

        // Add to list only the number part
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1)));
    }
}

in.close();

for (Integer i : list) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```